# Is it possible to upgrade and migrate TFS 2013 with SQL server 2016 to TFS 2017

Tags: sql-server-2016

We upgraded SQL 2012 to 2016 recently and now we are upgrading our TFS 2013 to TFS 2017. Due to the requirements of TFS 2013 indicating that TFS 2013 update 2 is compatible only with SQL server 2012 SP 1 or SQL server 2014 according to [docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts)

My question is:

Will I be able to update TFS 2013 directly to TFS 2017 if I have SQL 2016 already installed or do I have to climb the updated ladder with these two possible options:

**A**

1. TFS 2013 and downgrade to SQL Server 2012 (SP1)
2. TFS 2013 Update 2 with SQL Server 2014
3. TFS 2017 with SQL Server 2014
4. TFS 2017 Update 1 with SQL Server 2016

**B**

1. TFS 2013 and downgrade to SQL Server 2012 (SP1)
2. TFS 2015 Update 3 with SQL Server 2012 (SP1)
3. TFS 2017 with SQL Server 2016
4. TFS 2017 Update 1 with SQL Server 2016

If I have to climb the updated ladder which option would involve the least risk.

Comment: Have you backed up the TFS databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can upgrade TFS 2013 directly to TFS 2017. Since you have upgraded your SQL Server, you can install TFS 2017 and run the Team Foundation Server Configuration Wizard, select "I have existing databases to use for this Team Foundation Server deployment" option and "Production Upgrade" option during configuration. Here is a blog you can refer to:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/

It seems you're upgrading in place (not moving to new hardware), usually, we suggest do a [dry run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017) of your upgrade in a pre-production environment. Here is a helpful blog you can refer to:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/test-tfs-upgrades-pre-production-and-production-upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017-2/

Before upgrade, we also suggest read the article below which tells the general process for upgrading an existing deployment of Team Foundation Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/get-started?view=tfs-2018

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, i found the blogs to be very helpful.